# Text align left in a span

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph split up as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="nostyle">
  <p>
    <span class="heading">Really long heading</span><br>
    <br>
    Lots of text that needs to be justified
  </p>
</a>
```

The paragraph is set to `text-align: justify`, which it needs to stay at. 
I want just the `<span>` to be `text-align: left`, so that large gaps don't form between rows. How can I do this?

I want to keep it all as a single paragraph, as it's part of a flex item and having a `<h2>` and `<p>` means it won't all work nicely!

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, it's a bit unclear what the objective is and what you're attempting to overcome. Perhaps a diagram what the desired result and a few more details. Thanks!

Comment: You should post your complete problem and ideal outcome. This means posting the CSS and the `h2` and `p` elements you actually prefer. Try to avoid the [**XY Problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The page I'm using it on is http://www.greenlandexpeditions.com/guided-expeditions/ (still a work in progress).

I didn't want to use a separate <p> tag as the whole thing is part of a flex box and it was throwing that out. Seemed silly to have to rewrite anything to do with flex when all I needed was one line to be left aligned. 

Thanks for the feedback though, I will try and make this clearer in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that inline elements do not have a width and cannot be affected by `text-align`. To fix this, you can set the `<span>` to `display: block` and then it should display with the text aligned to the left, as shown in the snippet below.

NOTE: that I changed `text-align: justify` to `text-align: center` in the below snippet to make it easier to see.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

p span {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nostyle">
  <p>
    <span class="heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi convallis magna sit amet sollicitudin posuere. Vestibulum justo ex, lacinia dictum mollis et, egestas eu ipsum.</span><br>
    <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi convallis magna sit amet sollicitudin posuere. Vestibulum justo ex, lacinia dictum mollis et, egestas eu ipsum. Aliquam posuere purus vitae justo mollis lobortis vel vitae sapien.
    Sed sapien nibh, tincidunt sed risus vel, vestibulum euismod augue. Quisque molestie vehicula magna, eget pulvinar augue pellentesque nec. Praesent venenatis risus placerat dapibus rhoncus. Aliquam lacinia, dolor non tristique congue, est nunc bibendum
    erat, id varius augue turpis id ipsum.
  </p>
</a>
```

**However**, I really suggest using to `<p>` tags here because that's what they're for. Also note that you're using two `<br/>` tags to separate the span from the rest of the text and `<p>` tags implicitly have a `<br/>` before and after, so switching to multiple `<p>` would not change the spacing. See below:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

p.heading {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nostyle">
  <p class="heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi convallis magna sit amet sollicitudin posuere. Vestibulum justo ex, lacinia dictum mollis et, egestas eu ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi convallis magna sit amet sollicitudin posuere. Vestibulum justo ex, lacinia dictum mollis et, egestas eu ipsum. Aliquam posuere purus vitae justo mollis lobortis vel vitae sapien.
    Sed sapien nibh, tincidunt sed risus vel, vestibulum euismod augue. Quisque molestie vehicula magna, eget pulvinar augue pellentesque nec. Praesent venenatis risus placerat dapibus rhoncus. Aliquam lacinia, dolor non tristique congue, est nunc bibendum
    erat, id varius augue turpis id ipsum.
  </p>
</a>
```

Comment: Note that `<br>` does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: I know. It's a habit though..

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: If you're going to set an inline element to block level or replace it with a block level element might as well go with the desired element, `h2`.